# Re-arranging / -sorting DIVs without re-inserting into DOM

Tags: jquery, sorting, dom

I have several DIVs with content that have a data-weight-attribute which is updated regularly via AJAX.

I sort them in the loop where I iterate over the new values coming from the ajax-request.

Because the data-weight can be updated any time to any value, the order can change totally from update to update.

My sorting-logic seems flawed (to say the least ;)) because it only compares every element to its next via `.next()` so you have to click "Sort by data-weight" max. 4 times for 4 elements until they are sorted (see fiddle below)

It is important to know that the DIVs to be sorted contain external ressources like images, videos etc so it's important they are moved around and not re-created, because I think when re-inserted into the DOM, the contained ressources get re-loaded which is unacceptable for my use-case.

As it's hard to descripte and maybe understand, here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PdGTK/5/

**Update**

While the main problem is solved, there is still the problem that when f.e. Youtube-Videos are included, they are re-loaded every time the DIVs are reordered, even if the video doesn't change place in the DOM. That a) looks weird and b) interrupts the video-play.
Reading more about the topic, moving iframes in the DOM always seems to make them reload their content - how stupid is that?

Fiddle is updated with a fixed data-weight of 1 for the YT-video so it always stays on top.

http://jsfiddle.net/PdGTK/10/

Ideas very welcome!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's the first way that came to mind:

```
$("#sortButton").on("click", function () {
    var $wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
        $articles = $wrapper.find('.article');
    [].sort.call($articles, function(a,b) {
        return +$(a).attr('data-weight') - +$(b).attr('data-weight');
    });
    $articles.each(function(){
        $wrapper.append(this);
    });
});
```

Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/PdGTK/6/

Basically what that is doing is creating a jQuery object (`$articles`) that contains all of the articles. Then it sorts the items in the jQuery object according to their `data-weight` attribute. Then it goes through them in the new order and appends them to the wrapper - noting that when you `.append()` an item that is already in the DOM it gets moved.

Comment: At the end, why don't you do `$wrapper.append($articles)`?

Comment: @AlessandroVendruscolo - Because I'm not smart. (See also the opening sentence of my answer.) But yes, that should work.

Comment: thank you! That looks good. If I use @AlessandroVendruscolo s suggestion, wouldn't that hurt my point that they need to be moved rather than re-inserted?

Comment: Try it and see. If the short way doesn't work you can always go back to the `.each()`...

Comment: @nnnnnn Eheh, I thought you had a specific reason to iterate all over the collection.
@RaphaelJeger it should move the DOM elements. Actually no elements are removed or created, so when you do `append` them, they get moved around the DOM tree.

Comment: P.S. I forgot to say so in my answer, but (in case you're not familiar with the syntax) in my sort function I'm using the unary plus operator to convert the strings returned by `.attr()` into numbers.

Comment: so jQuery is smart enough to recognize that list of elements already exists? I thought that would only work if you throw one by one at it :)

Comment: that's great to know with the "+" operator because in my production code I was using "parseFloat()" atm, yours seems smarter. So I'm even dumber than you *lol*

Comment: Regarding Alessandro's suggestion, I think you'll find that it works fine because when you pass a jQuery object to `.append()` it will do an implicit `.each()` behind the scenes. (The implicit `.each()` occurs in a lot of jQuery methods that can accept individual elements or jQuery objects.)

Comment: @nnnnnn how can I "try it and see" - how can I test the objects are only moved and not re-inserted? Would I see that in firebugs network tool because inner images (for instance) would be re-fetched?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd expect you'd see for the resources. Or take a look at the jQuery source (and/or set a break point in the debugger and follow through the `.append()` operation).

Comment: It seems to work - almost. Youtube-Images make tons of get-requests though when they are in the DIV being moved according to firebug...

Answer (score 9):

This is how you can sort it:

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
    $art = $wrapper.children('.article');

$art.sort(function(a, b) {
    return +$(a).data('weight') - +$(b).data('weight');
})
.each(function() {
    $wrapper.append(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/PdGTK/8/

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work for me, but the lorempixel is great to know about. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work, doesn't it sort articles by data-weight?

Comment: exactly, on my machine (OSX / safari) it doesn't sort.

Comment: Hm, this is weird. `sort` method is available as prototype method, `data` method defined since jQuery 1.4. So this is strange.

Comment: The sort callback function is incorrect, specifically the `>` returns a boolean when the function should return a negative number, zero, or a positive number. Use `-` instead of `>` and it should be fine.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you, bad habbit.

Comment: @RaphaelJeger Sure it works for me, I wouldn't have posted if it didn't. Interesting. Does version by nnnnnn works for you?

Comment: now it's working like a charm. Thanks to both of you. So which one is better / more optimized of the 2 answers? This runs quite often and on a quite complicated DOM so that'd be good to know.

Comment: @dfsq - Do you know why the jQuery doco doesn't (that I can find) indicate that you can use `.sort()` directly on a jQuery object? (You certainly can't use all array methods directly...) I don't like to use undocumented features, which is why my answer used `[].sort.call(...`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Probably you are right and your approach is more reliable. Take a look [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L258). They attach reference to `[].sort` to the jQuery prototype but also point that this is only for internal usage.

Comment: is there any way to sort elements with animation?

Comment: @ArpitArya of course. just implement sorting algorithm yourself instead of using build in sort method. Then for every item your would calculate its top position based in the new index in array. With CSS transition it's easy to make such position change animated.

Comment: I got it to work in this format, using appendTo: ```$('.container .child').sort((a,b) => +score(a)-score(b)).appendTo('.container');``` where `score` is a function returning a number for a dom element - noting that source and destination container elements may be different elements, and source can include multiple containers

Answer (score 5):

I need too re-order elements without re-inserting into DOM.
You can do it by modify CSS property.

For outer container set CSS property:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

and for each element set:

```
order: X;
```

where X growing in ascending order.

Comment: that's a good idea and for re-arranging just set the order new

Comment: Useful as the order can be set from JS using `element.style.order = X`.