# Re-arranging / -sorting DIVs without re-inserting into DOM without targeting container

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I've set the subject very similar to another question because that one solves partially my problem and I can't comment.

([Re-arranging / -sorting DIVs without re-inserting into DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129259/re-arranging-sorting-divs-without-re-inserting-into-dom))

What if I have some elements to sort and some not ? I know some elements will be together then have to resort themselfs but without moving some others

```
<div class=nosort ></div>
<div class=nosort ></div>
<div class=tosort1 data-sort=3 ></div>
<div class=tosort1 data-sort=1 ></div>
<div class=tosort1 data-sort=2 ></div>
<div class=tosort1 data-sort=4 ></div>
<div class=nosort ></div>
<div class=nosort ></div>
<div class=tosort2 data-sort=3 ></div>
<div class=tosort2 data-sort=1 ></div>
<div class=tosort2 data-sort=6 ></div>
<div class=tosort2 data-sort=2 ></div>
<div class=tosort2 data-sort=5 ></div>
<div class=tosort2 data-sort=4 ></div>
<div class=nosort ></div>
<div class=tosort3 data-sort=4 ></div>
<div class=tosort3 data-sort=3 ></div>
<div class=tosort3 data-sort=1 ></div>
<div class=tosort3 data-sort=6 ></div>
<div class=tosort3 data-sort=5 ></div>
<div class=tosort3 data-sort=2 ></div>
<div class=nosort ></div>
<div class=nosort ></div>
```

All the solution I've found have to target a wrapper and re-append the elements inside it, but I will lose position also for those element not to sort

Comment: You could extract the `nosort` record their positional index and sorts the `data-sort` element. Then re-inject the `nosort` elements into the positions they were before, starting at the end off course, last to first.

Comment: I've discarded this solution because the process will involve really too many elements, then it would be too slow !

Comment: It shouldn't be slow enough to notice unless you're dealing with several thousand elements, which would be a problem in itself that you should address first.

Comment: Not thousand, but maybe hundred. Find a solution that sorts only those 4 that you see in example will be best, isn't it possible ?

Comment: @Gulp oh, you never write to the DOM line by line, that would be crazy :) You can do it in memory, writing it into a variable wrapper, then when you are done dump all simultaneously back into the DOM or you can even detach and re-attach the DOM sections.

Comment: Sure, I'm not intended to write directly to the DOM, but this operation will be done many times on many other elements, then I'm searching for the lighter solution, if it exists
(I've edited the question to show a more complex example, maybe it clarifies better)